# What were the most controversial thesis' of the Scholastics?

Tags: middle-ages, catholic-church

What actual theses were controversial and caused a stir at the time (not today) in the sense of having the most amount of written response? What specific questions were defended in actual theses by scholars at the time, along the line of:

- What is the order of the outer heavens?
- Jesus had no possessions
- How many angels fit on a pinhead? (though I doubt this was a real thesis!)

The Scholastics date from approximately the 13th to the 15th centuries, during which time the early European philosophers such as [Albertus Magnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertus_Magnus), [Thomas Aquinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Acquinas), [Duns Scotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duns_Scotus), etc., made their mark. Their philosophy is still hotly discussed today.

I have done research, but my research is complicated by a form of historical survivor bias. Today we get the impression that the most important topic in medieval universities was [nominalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalism), but I'm certain the questions were much more theological. My goal is to understand the topics they discussed, not just the ones that are most interesting to the modern mind.

Comment: "What in your opinion..." per...haps not the best place to ask this...Close votes will be after you in no time.

Comment: What research have you done so far? This sounds much like a homework question, in which case, what does your textbook say?

Comment: I'm not a student, but I have an interest in medieval history. There isn't that much online material on actual theses titles.

Comment: I imagine that what is controversial or not is subject to opinion.... but what was controversial at the time should be more objective.

Comment: Please help me out here: This is not a question meant to stir debate. It is meant to understand the past. Today we get the impression that the most important topic in medieval universities was nominalism, but I'm certain the questions were much more theological.

Comment: Please edit the research comments *into the question*.  Then edit the he auestion away from opinion, without making it a list question.  Difficult, but doable.  I cannot do it from cellphone, but will try tomorrow from laptop unl ss some other helpful person beats me to it.

Comment: This could be a good and interesting question if edited.

Comment: Loved this debate in *The Name of the Rose*, some history here:  https://muse.jhu.edu/article/177380

Comment: I understand that this question is in the spirit of understanding the past, but how do you judge "most controversial"? Thesis A might be more controversial than B for some people but the opposite for other people. Such questions are discouraged by house rules due to various reasons.

Comment: @user69715 ... "in the sense of having the most amount of written response". It is not modern historians' judgements that the question is about, but those at the time. One major controversy at the time, which is not at all a controversy nowadays, is whether Jesus had possessions; it was controversial because it had major repercussions for the Church. It would be interesting to have a small list of these theses.